# How to add a custom field after wp post

Tags: posts, custom-field, title, visual-editor

I want a subtitle box after the title.

How to show it in the post editor?

[image: post editor]

Comment: You can use the `edit_form_before_permalink` action: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_form_before_permalink/
You'll have to add your custom css rules and logic for saving and getting the value too, For so, you can use the `save_post` action: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post